# Caption package not working with beamer

Tags: beamer, captions, fontsize

I am using `beamer` to make a presentation. But the default caption font size seems big to me. So I tried to make the font size smaller using `caption` package. I tried this:

```
\usepackage[center,scriptsize]{caption}
```

Also:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={footnotesize},labelfont={footnotesize}}
```

But they don't seem to make the caption font size smaller. **Where am I going wrong?**

My preamble is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usetheme{default}
```

And my caption code is:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{axb-grid}
  \caption{$A \times B$ grid}
  \label{fig:axbgrid}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need the `caption` package for this.

Simply issue the command

```
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
```

MWE

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx} % remove in your document
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usetheme{default}

\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{axb-grid}
  \caption{$A \times B$ grid}
  \label{fig:axbgrid}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

While with old versions of `beamer`, `caption` commands used to work, it seems that now the `caption` package is not able to recognize `beamer` anymore.

In fact, loading `caption` with `beamer` you get the following warning:

> Package `caption` Warning: `\caption` will not be redefined since it's already
>
> (`caption`)                redefined by a document class or package which is
>
> (`caption`)                unknown to the `caption` package.
>
> See the `caption` package documentation for explanation.

If you want `caption` and its `\captionsetup` to work with `beamer`, you have to load `caption` with the option `compatibility=false`:

```
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
```

but, as the documentation warns:

> But please note that using this option is neither recommended
> nor supported since unwanted side-effects or even errors could occur afterwards.

Comment: Thanx, this works like a charm. But I still would like to know why caption package is not working. Hence, I can't accept your answer.

Comment: @th1rdey3 do you think that now it can be accepted?

Comment: There was a typo in the `beamer` code, which needed fixing for other reasons. Regrettably, `caption` checks for this defective definition before coming into action: a fix is needed in `caption`.

Comment: @JosephWright thanks for this clarification.

Comment: Interesting, I am using miktex with gvim tex-plugin. This warning didn't show up when I compiled.

Comment: @th1rdey3 Probably it is not so responsive to warnings, as my editor is. Anyway, you can try searching it in the `.log` file.

Comment: Thanks for asking and answering, this was driving me nuts: unable to compile last year's code argh!! back in control now  :-)

Comment: So is there any "clean" way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

These Issues have been cleared and should be closed in 2019 versions of the packages

Please update to Tex Live 2019 (Note W32TeX / MiKTeX are generally already updated)

[image]