# How to define additional \caption* like command for Latex beamer?

Tags: beamer, captions

`beamer` currently is incompatible with the `caption` package ([as described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155738/caption-package-not-working-with-beamer)). I would like to define an additional command that works like the `\caption*` command of that package, i.e. typesets the caption without label and without entry in the list of tables/figures, but has the same formatting as the regular `\caption`-command. Important: I do still need the normal `\caption` command, so I cannot just globally redefine `\setbeamertemplate{caption}`

I am thinking about something along the lines of

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Some title}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      A & B \\
      C & D \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some numbered Table and its description. Even more and more and more text.}
  \end{table}

  \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      A & B \\
      C & D \\
    \end{tabular}
  \caption*{Some unnumbered Table and its description. Even more and more and more text.}
  \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a small document to your question illustrating the problem. Then people can copy-paste-compile and experiment to find a solution, making it much easier to help and reducing the chances that an answer won't work for you.

Comment: @cfr I added a minimum non-working example, but I don't think that will be helpful as the problem is caused by a bug in `caption` (as pointed out by Joseph Wright) and I am looking for a different approach not involving that package.

Comment: Do you have to call it \caption* ? All it does is write a caption without using or incrementing  the float counter.  The center environment will do that.

Comment: @JohnKormylo The center environment will center it, but the default `\caption` in beamer will be left-aligned. Of course, I could manually make them similar. But the goal is to inherit the formatting from the original `\caption` command

Comment: That's not what I see when I run your MWE (with \caption* removed).  Anyway, you can test for the beamer class and use different definitions based on context.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I adjusted the MWE. If I remove the `\caption*` the second line is centered in the bottom table.

Comment: The example ***is*** helpful. Without it, anybody helping has to start a document from scratch. With it, they can just concentrate on the bit you need help with. So thanks for adding it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it; `\caption*` inherits the same formatting as `\caption` (in particular, it has the same skips above and below and the single line feature):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{xparse}

\LetLtxMacro\oldcaption\caption

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand\caption{som}{
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {
      \setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[none]
      \def\insertcaptionname{}%
      \def\insertcaptionnumber{}%
      \def\insertcaption{#3}%
      \nobreak\vskip\abovecaptionskip\nobreak
      \sbox\@tempboxa{\usebeamertemplate**{caption}}%
      \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
        \usebeamertemplate**{caption}\par
      \else
      \global \@minipagefalse
        \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
      \fi
      \nobreak\vskip\belowcaptionskip\nobreak
    }
    {\oldcaption[#2]{#3}}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\TestTable{%
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      A & B \\
    \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Some title}

\begin{table}
\TestTable
\caption{Some numbered Table and its description. Even more and more and more text.}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\TestTable
\caption*{Some unnumbered Table and its description. Even more and more and more text.}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\TestTable
\caption{Some numbered Table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\TestTable
\caption*{Some unnumbered Table}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```