# Miktex compiler fails to compile my presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, equations

The following [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vpf2ngfr5is7r2y/Second%20year%20ISA.zip?dl=0) is for a presenation I am preparing for a presentation tomorrow.

The surprising thing is that it does not compile using MikTex 2.9. Although the latest updates have been installed. The latest successful compilation point is before adding the equation environment.

What surprises me is that it compiles successfully on Overleaf with just one warning message for running in backward compatibility mode. Nothing else!

Is there somehting I am doing wrong such that not all compilers can "swallow" my code?

N.B: I am using `Dresden` theme with some modifications to suit the visual communication of our institution.

Comment: It can't be downloaded freely.

Comment: @Bernard Could you please check? I have tried to download from an anonymous device and it works.

Comment: I'm sorry: I can see a  2nd_isa.tex file, by I can't copy it.  If that is a problematic file, can't you add it to your post?

Comment: As commented below I have no problem compiling your or alternative version. Llike you In overleaf in my MiKTeX I only got the comatability warning to add a compatability ref in preamble e.g. line 95 ( \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} clears that message) looking at my console output residual comments are several **PDF inclusion: found PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed** (this is because Soda has added that 1.7 tag) also I see one comment **Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MiKTeX font mapping does not seem to work 100% correctly! In practice I made the steps he advised but no luck. Opening the log file the interesting part is

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file mathkerncmssi12): Font mathkerncmssi12 at 600
not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Based on a [similar issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53808/miktex-font-ccicons-at-600-not-found) on StackExchange, I ran the same commands but for `mathkerncmssi12` code as follows:

1- On Win run CMD as admin.

2- Run `initexmf --admin --edit-config-file updmap`

3- It opens the file in Notepad (Win platforms).

4- Put the following in the file `Map mathkerncmssi12.map` in the file & save.

5- Back on CMD run `initexmf --admin --mkmaps`.

6- You are done! Now back to LaTeX with no problems!.

Comment: initexmf  --mkmaps is in my default startup (every time) the difference is you had to run as admin (do you have a multi user set-up, to be avoided) so running console as admin should have been able to run task update font maps

Answer (score 2):

The relevant error message in your log file is:

> ```
> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file mathkerncmssi8): Font mathkerncmssi8 at 450 n
> ot found
>  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
> ```

I think your font maps are not okay or you simply did not install the missing font.

Open your MiKTeX Console, Click on `Tasks`, then `Refresh font map files`

Please report if it solves the issue ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version of your presentation. The main issue was for caption package incompatibility [[check this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155738/caption-package-not-working-with-beamer)]. (search for "@SARI" word in the code below to see my comments).

```
\documentclass [12pt]{beamer}
% Remember you have a limited set of sizes to choose from, any unrecognised value will be considered as default. Therefore, you MUST choose from: 8pt, 9pt, 10pt, 11pt, 12pt, 14pt, 17pt, 20pt. Default 11pt in Beamer package
\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Dresden}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usecolortheme{lsc}

}

\mode<handout>{
  % tema simples para ser impresso
  \usepackage[bar]{beamerthemetree}
  % Colocando um fundo cinza quando for gerar transparências para serem impressas
  % mais de uma transparência por página
  \beamertemplatesolidbackgroundcolor{black!5}
}

\usepackage{amsmath}%,amssymb}
%\usepackage[brazil]{varioref} %These packages use local languages for figure numbers
%\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
%
%% >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>PACKAGES SET BY MAZEN SHANAWANI <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%\usepackage{caption} %@SARI:: CAUSES ERROR
\setbeamersize{text margin left=3mm,text margin right=3mm} 
\setbeamerfont{caption name}{size=\footnotesize}
%\usepackage[justification=centering, textfont={footnotesize}]{caption} %labelfont=footnotesize,  % %@SARI:: CAUSES ERROR
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}%USE THIS COMMAND INSTEAD @SARI::
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%%\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} %Required for BB figure
\usetikzlibrary{
    fadings,
    shapes.arrows,
    shadows,
    arrows.meta, % has replaced the old arrows library
    positioning,
    calc,
    bending, % better arrow tips on curved lines
    graphs, %Required for BB figure
    datavisualization.formats.functions %Required for BB figure
}
\beamertemplatetransparentcovereddynamic


% Space for added functionality and codes
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
  \node [xshift=3cm,yshift=0cm, opacity=0.3] at (current page.west)
  {\includegraphics[height=0.6\paperheight]{figs/Bologo.pdf}};              
\end{tikzpicture}%
}{}

\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

\title[THZ \& mm]{Terahertz \\and \\ millimetric rectennas}
\author[Mazen Shanawani]{
  Mazen Shanawani
}
  \institute[DEI/CAMPI]{
     Laboratorio dei campi elettromagnetici\\
     DIPARTIMENTO DELL’ENERGIA ELETTRICA E DELL’INFORMAZIONE \\DEI \\
     Guglielmo Marconi
}

%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width = 5cm]{figs/Bologo.pdf}}
% Se comentar a linha abaixo, irá aparecer a data quando foi compilada a apresentação  
\date{11 December 2018}


%\pgfdeclareimage[height=1cm]{inf}{figs/CienciaDaComputacao.png}

% pode-se colocar o LOGO assim
%\logo{\pgfuseimage{inf}}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Agenda}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Agenda}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\section{Introduction}

\frame{
    \frametitle{Transfer Matrix Method TMM}
    \begin{columns}[c]
        \column{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Compromise between complexity and accuracy.
                \item Ability to simulate multi insulator structure.
                \item Better mathematical accuracy.
                \item {\textcolor{unibored}{Now optimizer uses genetic algorithm to search for optimum solution (best figures of merit)}}
            \end{itemize}
        \column{0.5\textwidth}

        %\begin{figure}[htbp]   
        %   \centering
        %   \includegraphics[width= \textwidth]{figs/TMM_standalone.pdf}
        %   \caption{Classification of theory of operation}
        %\end{figure}
        \begin{equation}
            \psi_j(x) = A_j \cdot e^{p_j(x)} + B_j \cdot e^{-p_j(x)}
        \end{equation}
    \end{columns}
}
\section{References}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]

  \frametitle<presentation>{References}
  \tiny {
    \begin{thebibliography}{10}
        \bibitem [1] {Mlinar2013} 
        Mlinar, V.
        \newblock Engineered nanomaterials for solar energy conversion.
        \newblock {\em Nanotechnology} {\bf 2013 }, {\em 042001}.

        \bibitem [2] {Nagel2016}
        Nagel, R.D.; Haeberle, T.; Schmidt, M.; Lugli, P.; Scarpa, G. 
        \newblock Large Area Nano-transfer Printing of Sub-50-nm Metal Nanostructures Using Low-cost Semi-flexible Hybrid Templates.
        \newblock Article; {\em Nanoscale Res. Lett. }{\bf 2016}, {\em 11, 143}. 

        \bibitem [3] {Shanawani201702}
        Shanawani, M.; Masotti, D.; Costanzo, A.
        \newblock THz Rectennas and Their Design Rules. \newblock {\em Electronics} {\bf 2017}, {\em 6, 99}. 

        \bibitem [4] {Corkish2002}
        Corkish, R.; Green, M.; Puzzer, T.
        \newblock Solar energy collection by antennas.
        \newblock {\em Sol. Energy} {\bf 2002}, {\em 73},~395--401.

        \bibitem [5] {Mlinar2013} 
        Mlinar, V.
        \newblock Engineered nanomaterials for solar energy conversion.
        \newblock {\em Nanotechnology} {\bf 2013 }, {\em 042001}.

    \end{thebibliography}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even in the file I uploaded the package `caption` is commented. Yet it does not run on my MiKTeX. As I said it does run without problems on Overleaf but still the problem persists on MiKTeX.

Comment: I do not have MikTeX. It was tested on Texlive 2018. Try to updated MikTeX to 2018 and try again.

Comment: I am running current MiKTeX updated early this month. with or without commented \..{caption} I have no problem compiling 6 pages, should there be more? only warning I get is 2 for pgfplots on line 96

Comment: MIKTEX and W3sTeX do not need a caption bug fix for beamer it was cleared during previous updates that bug fix is only needed for TeX Live until 2019 is released the error messages here are font related