# Texmaker doesn't compile pdf

Tags: compiling, texmaker

I am using Texmaker on Mac to compile some scripts. The same scripts work on other Mac computers but not mine: when I click on Quick build, it says

> ```
> Could not start the command.
> pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
> ```

So the PDF file does not update.

I have searched online, and see some answers recommending to change the command preferences. However, the preferences in my system doesn't seem wrong:

[image]

Also, after I click on Quick build, Texmaker doesn't generate other files as it does on other computers. That is, I still only have the `.tex` file in the folder.

Could anyone help me with this? What should I change?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just some thoughts. Are the settings on the different mac's identical? Did you install a LaTeX distribution on the system where the compilation fails? In case the it is installed is e.g. the program pdflatex available in the path? Did you start TexMaker by means of a "double click"? In the later case did you relogin after installing LaTeX?

Comment: Is MacTeX installed on your computer? Installing TeXmaker does not imply that MacTeX is installed...

Comment: @albert Thank you for the fast reply! The settings are the same, and I just re-installed the Texmaker on this laptop where the compilation fails. What do you mean by "the program pdflatex available in the path?" Yes, I start TexMaker by double clicking the .tex file. I don't think it asks me to login..?

Comment: @Mico I don't have MacTex...but the other laptop doesn't have it either... Is this why it fails?

Comment: @Tian - if no TeX distribution is installed your computer, that would certainly explain why the document can't be compiled. Remember that TeXmaker is just a "front end" to a TeX distribution.

Comment: @ Ohh that makes sense! I am downloading MacTex and hope it solves the problem, Thanks a lot for the advice! (Probably I downloaded the distribution on the other mac and forgot about it...)

Comment: @Tian You have to reinstall Texmaker _after_ the installation of MacTeX.

Comment: @Tian... this is another problem not related to this question... I am sure your code is already minimal... and thus in the new question you will ask... just place your code as an example that demonstrates this new problem (Possible title: "Undefined control sequence in minimal a `beamer` document" ... your code below and an answer in minutes)

Comment: @Mico Thanks a lot for the suggestion! Installing MacTex solved all the problem!

Comment: @koleygr My bad - it now does work on a minimal beamer document. I will try to fix what's wrong in my original beamer scripts.

Comment: Try to add the original code inside the minimal code (part by part) and compile every time... You will find the error and will learn basic debugging too (that is even better than finding an error)

Comment: @koleygr Thanks a lot for the strategy! Yes I found the bug by adding one package/frame each time! The error occurs with "usepackage{caption}". Once I comment this line out, the whole document compiles smoothly. I used this package to create "\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{Source: {#1}} }", in order to show the source of figures, but not sure why the caption package doesn't work now...

Comment: @Tian: We are offtopic and I will not answer again here... but check this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155740/120578

Comment: @koleygr Thank you for the suggestion! I just posted a new question regarding this, and will check the link you sent!

Comment: It is possible you have a choice of editors and a means to update Tex-Live styles fonts etc  use TeX Live Utility, installed by MacTeX in /Applications/TeX (however this issue with caption package might not be solved until the engine updates which will change in April with MacTeX 2019) to see more notes on what you may have installed along with MacTeX see https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/whereisstuff.html

Comment: @KJO Thank you for the explanation! This is very helpful!